Adding an IF Clause to a SQL statement
I have an SQL Query that looks like this.
      SELECT T.order
           ,COUNT(T.[reason]) as Qty
           ,MAX(T.[updatedate]) as Date
           ,F.startdate
           ,F.ID        
      FROM [Table T] T
     inner join [Table F] F on T.order = F.order and F.ID = T.ID
      where T.ID IS NOT NULL
          and T.NEWID IS NOT NULL
          and T.batch IS NOT NULL    
      and T.updatedate < F.startdate
      group by
            T.order
               ,F.startdate
                   ,F.ID

I want to add an IF clause that goes like this.
IF F.startdate IS NULL SET F.startdate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
How do I go by adding the IF clause in my above query? The IF clause is to have a dedicated date when if it's null.
Tried adding the clause after the where statement, but it's not working.

Please the tag RDBMS you're using

You can't update values in a table in a select statement. If you just want to return a different value on null in the select, use coalesce

COALESCE(F.startdate, '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000')

Or, doing it the long way with a CASE expression: CASE WHEN F.startdate IS NULL THEN '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000' ELSE F.startdate END
